# Table cells with space between them

Tags: html, css

I want to make the following but with CSS classes - as simple as can be:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="color:red;text-decoration:underline;padding-right:50px;">cell1</td>
        <td style="color:red;text-decoration:underline;">cell2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="color:red;text-decoration:underline;padding-right:50px;">cell3</td>
        <td style="color:red;text-decoration:underline;">cell4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS equivalent for `<table cellspacing="0">` is

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

And for `<table cellpadding="0">` is

```
table td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

So, this should do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 4528942</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table td {
                padding: 0;
                color: red;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            table td:first-child {
                padding-right: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>cell1</td>
                <td>cell2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cell3</td>
                <td>cell4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

Markup

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cell1</td>
        <td>cell2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell3</td>
        <td>cell4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table td {color:#ff0000; text-decoration:underline;}
table td:first-child {padding-right:50px;}
```

Comment: What about the: cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" ?

Comment: In my markup, there is no cellspacing or cellpadding (besides the right padding) so you don't need to set the values in the table

Answer (score 0):

The right solution really depends on your use case. When you're creating markup, it's really important to consider the content that is going to be inside. A table might me the right answer for a something such as a calendar whereas a box layout might fit better in the case of an image gallery.

Here is a tableless proposal to your problem, I hope it's useful :)

```
<style>
  #container{
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .cell{
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
  }
</style>
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell 3</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS for this table

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```